# Sin and other events, illness, prayer

Tags: tefilla, choleh-sick

In charismatic-christianity, "healing-preachers" pray for someone to get better. They first check whether something happened to the person, like sin or a dramatic event that might block the healing.

Q1] In Judaism, are there people who can pray for someone to get better?

Q2] If yes, are there events which occurred before the person got sick that can block the prayer.

Comment: sounds like this is off topic

Comment: @dude the question is about Jewish practice.

Answer (score 2):

The gemoro [Nedarim 40](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/memdb/revdaf.php?tid=16&id=40) explains how important it is that anyone who visits the sick should pray for the sick person while visiting.

Any sort of suffering, including illness, can be brought about by having sinned, see [here](http://www.torah.org/features/spirfocus/suffering.html) . The sin can be a barrier to recovery but repentance can remove the barrier.

[This article by the Chicago Community Kollel](http://www.cckollel.org/parsha_encounters/5767/toldos.pdf) points out the importance of the righteous person in praying for a sick person and says:

> The Shulchan Aruch states that one who has a choleh in his house
>   should consult with a talmid chacham (Torah sage) to daven (pray) for him (Y. D. 335-10).
>   How do we understand this concept and what is the actual role of the
>   tzaddik (righteous person) when he is consulted? The Meiri writes (Taanis 8A) that the
>   real purpose of visiting a tzaddik is in order for the tzaddik to
>   advise him on the proper course of teshuva (repentance) and tefilla
>   (prayer).
>
> The Sefer Chasidim (755) writes that the tzaddik should investigate
>   the petitioners’ ways to see if perhaps there is a particular sin
>   which may be the cause of this persons’ troubles. The tzaddik should
>   then tell the person, “If you want me to daven for you, you must fix
>   yourself in this particular area”.

So we see that

- everyone can pray for someone to get better
- a particularly righteous person can be more effective and should try 
  to see if a particular sin causes  this person's troubles.